# Twitter No such element error python-selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

After printing the username on the login screen on twitter, I want it to press the login button, but I get a "no such element" error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://twitter.com/login"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[autocomplete='username']"))).send_keys("bla")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button'][contains(.,'Next')]").click()
```

i try with do xpath css selector but never work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me!
With no changes

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://twitter.com/login"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[autocomplete='username']"))).send_keys("bla")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button'][contains(.,'Next')]").click()
```

The result is - we went to the next page
I tried several times.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your driver opens twitter with English texts? Maybe it presents Turkish so the expected text is not found?

Comment: u know what langue kod. my browser is eng but python openin turkish

Comment: I don't understand. When you run this Selenium Python code. in what locale is opened a browser opened with driver? Is it presenting English or Turkish texts? Especially on "Next" button

Comment: //span[contains(text(),'İleri')]    yes doing like this

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "doing like this"? Still not working with the same exception or works correctly?

Comment: I wanted to say  "//div[@role='button'][contains(.,'Next')]" If I write "İleri" in Turkish instead of Next in the code It gives this error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 34: invalid continuation byte

Comment: OK, but what text is **actually** presented on your browser opened by Selenium????? Turkish or English

Comment: browser opening turkish

Comment: So, how can you expect English texts there? It's clear such element is not existing there!

Comment: To overcome this problem you need to know how to pass Turkish letters into the XPath locator or just use **partial** string that do not contain problematic letters.

Comment: If I write the Turkish word I expect there, it gives another error.

Comment: i think i will reformat my computer to english to solve this